# Read specific element from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to bind the MultipleCheckbox items from Choice Column of sharepoint List to asp.net CheckBoxListItem using c#. I am retriving information of List using XELEMENT as:

```
XElement listStructure;

listStructure = proxy.GetList("WebsiteSubscriber");
```

```xml
<Field Type="MultiChoice" DisplayName="Area" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" FillInChoice="FALSE" ID="{16cc1615-a490-44de-a870-c7ebe603e2cc}" SourceID="{2c8a80ea-38c5-48f7-9d7d-400d445a5e64}" StaticName="Area" Name="Area" ColName="ntext2" RowOrdinal="0">
  <Default>Articles</Default>
  <CHOICES>
    <CHOICE>Articles</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Websites</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Books</CHOICE>
  </CHOICES>
</Field>
```

I want to read choices from this XML. and get values only "Articles,Websites,Books"

**Note:** This XML may contain many sections with `<choices>` i want to fetech it by `<fieldType>` or the DisplayName="Area" attribute and get values in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var temp = 
    listStructure.Descendants("Field")
                 .Where(i => i.Attribute("DisplayName").Value == "Area")
                             .Select(i => i.Descendants("CHOICE") 
                                          .Select(j => j.Value)).ToList();

List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (IEnumerable<string> item in temp)
{
    result.AddRange(item);
}

//result: Articles; Websites; Books
```

Comment: hello @Hossein Narimani Rad sorry to say but, i am using XElement which returns the xml and not the xml file.

Comment: Here is my full xml files structure: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/XbSY9BEMpB/   this is what i am getting result after quering the XElement. the content is this file is result of Xelement and not the xml file. PLZ Help!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE seems the problem is with your first line! I opened it in the notepad and it displays in two line. I turn off the `wordwrap` and again it was in two line. So I remove second line and close the `List` tag by `>`. Now the every thing is working!

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = @"<Field Type=""MultiChoice"" DisplayName=""Area"" Required=""FALSE"" EnforceUniqueValues=""FALSE"" Indexed=""FALSE"" FillInChoice=""FALSE"" ID=""{16cc1615-a490-44de-a870-c7ebe603e2cc}"" SourceID=""{2c8a80ea-38c5-48f7-9d7d-400d445a5e64}"" StaticName=""Area"" Name=""Area"" ColName=""ntext2"" RowOrdinal=""0"">
  <Default>Articles</Default>
  <CHOICES>
    <CHOICE>Articles</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Websites</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Books</CHOICE>
  </CHOICES>
</Field>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XElement element = 
         doc.Descendants("Field")
            .First(field => (string)field.Attribute("DisplayName") == "Area");


string[] result = 
         element.Descendants("CHOICE")
                .Select(v => (string)v)
                .ToArray();


Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

prints:

```
Articles
Websites
Books
```

Comment: hello @llya lvanov plz note i am using XElement and not static text. plz let me know how to traverse XElement..?

Comment: Error: Squence contains no matching element. shall i need to convert the Xelement result to XDocument?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE apparenly you use xml, which you haven't provided. It's hard to solve your problem without that xml. I've updated my answer to a more generic solution, but again - it's just a attempt

Comment: Here is my full xml files structure: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/XbSY9BEMpB/   this is what i am getting result after quering the XElement. the content is this file is result of Xelement and not the xml file. PLZ HELP !